# Debian Screen freeze

Tags: debian, freeze, gpu

We have a `Debian Linux (8.11)` that freezes the monitor output over and over again. The computer is still accessible over the network. But it will not send any changes to the monitor the graphic device is a `VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)` The Monitor is connected over a DVI cable.

Is there any option to check if a problem between Monitor and Graphic device? The screen is not black but the image on the screen is not changing. But if we connect with VLC Viewer we see the correct screen.

I have found the `intel_gpu_top` tool is there any other option to check?

Comment: It probably needs some boot parameters but I don't have any experience with those crappy Bay Trail CPUs, other than knowing they're probably the worse for Linux.

Comment: What I mean in the first comment is that it's a known problem with that CPU/GPU in Linux.